# Why my arm64 android emulator in android studio crashed?

Tags: android

I am unable to launch an arm64 android emulator at android studio 2021.3.1 Patch 1. I’m running it on Windows 11 with Intel i7 core.

Log output:

```
2022-12-26 15:48:08,948 [  20778]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - C:\Users\dingy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_6_API_33 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300 
2022-12-26 15:48:08,987 [  20817]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Android emulator version 31.3.14.0 (build_id 9322596) (CL:N/A) 
2022-12-26 15:48:08,987 [  20817]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - emulator: INFO: Found systemPath C:\Users\dingy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis\arm64-v8a\ 
2022-12-26 15:48:08,987 [  20817]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host. 
2022-12-26 15:48:08,987 [  20817]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Process finished with exit code 1 
2022-12-26 15:48:08,993 [  20823]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 33 - Emulator terminated with exit code 1
```

config.ini:

```ini
AvdId=Pixel_6_API_33
PlayStore.enabled=false
abi.type=arm64-v8a
avd.ini.displayname=Pixel 6 API 33
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
disk.dataPartition.size=800M
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile=
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot=no
fastboot.forceColdBoot=no
fastboot.forceFastBoot=yes
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.arc=false
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.camera.back=virtualscene
hw.camera.front=emulated
hw.cpu.arch=arm64
hw.cpu.ncore=4
hw.dPad=no
hw.device.hash2=MD5:3db3250dab5d0d93b29353040181c7e9
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
hw.device.name=pixel_6
hw.gps=yes
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.gpu.mode=auto
hw.initialOrientation=Portrait
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.lcd.density=420
hw.lcd.height=2400
hw.lcd.width=1080
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.ramSize=1536
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.trackBall=no
image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-33\google_apis\arm64-v8a\
runtime.network.latency=none
runtime.network.speed=full
sdcard.size=512M
showDeviceFrame=yes
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.name=pixel_6
skin.path=C:\Users\dingy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\skins\pixel_6
tag.display=Google APIs
tag.id=google_apis
vm.heapSize=228
```

I found android source:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/1381d44efe69ba0b37fb7f7ef868125e279fc14a/android/emulator/main-emulator.cpp#910

```cpp
          if (sarch == "arm64" && apiLevel >=28) {
              APANIC("Avd's CPU Architecture '%s' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host.\n", avdarch);
          }
```

And tried a API 27 image, it crashed:

```
2022-12-26 15:37:46,506 [1111142]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - C:\Users\dingy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_6_API_27 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300 
2022-12-26 15:37:46,533 [1111169]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - Android emulator version 31.3.14.0 (build_id 9322596) (CL:N/A) 
2022-12-26 15:37:46,533 [1111169]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - emulator: INFO: Found systemPath C:\Users\dingy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\arm64-v8a\ 
2022-12-26 15:37:47,096 [1111732]   WARN -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\dingy\.android\avd\Pixel_6_API_27.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading. 
2022-12-26 15:37:47,191 [1111827]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. 
2022-12-26 15:37:47,191 [1111827]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - IPv4 server found: 192.168.1.1 
2022-12-26 15:37:47,219 [1111855]   INFO - ab.VirtualDeviceChangeListener - emulator-5554 connected 
2022-12-26 15:37:47,219 [1111855]   WARN -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - *** Basic token auth will be deprecated soon, please migrate to using -grpc-use-jwt *** 
2022-12-26 15:37:47,220 [1111856]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: +token 
2022-12-26 15:37:47,470 [1112106]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - Advertising in: C:\Users\dingy\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_2292.ini 
2022-12-26 15:37:47,474 [1112110]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - C:\Users\dingy\AppData\Loc 
2022-12-26 15:37:47,474 [1112110]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - al\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-aarch64.exe: PCI bus not available for hda 
2022-12-26 15:37:47,537 [1112173]   WARN - ea.emulator.EmulatorController - android.emulation.control.EmulatorController/getDisplayConfigurations call failed - FAILED_PRECONDITION: The multi-display feature is not available 
2022-12-26 15:39:17,909 [1202545]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Health check heartbeat 
2022-12-26 15:39:37,093 [1221729]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 main loop'. No response for 109874 ms 
2022-12-26 15:39:37,093 [1221729]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1  Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335 
2022-12-26 15:39:37,096 [1221732]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - JDK: 11.0.13; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2022-12-26 15:39:37,096 [1221732]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - OS: Windows 11
```

Then I tried opening emulator.exe with IDA Pro, modify `cmp     esi, 27` with `cmp     esi, 999` at `.text:0000000140002B3F`, and patch it.
It crashed again:

```
2022-12-26 16:41:17,662 [1055922]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - C:\Users\dingy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_6_API_27 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300 
2022-12-26 16:41:17,683 [1055943]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - Android emulator version 31.3.14.0 (build_id 9322596) (CL:N/A) 
2022-12-26 16:41:17,683 [1055943]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - emulator: INFO: Found systemPath C:\Users\dingy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\arm64-v8a\ 
2022-12-26 16:41:19,484 [1057744]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - Process finished with exit code -1073741795 (0xC000001D) 
2022-12-26 16:41:19,484 [1057744]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 6 API 27 - Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741795 
java.lang.Throwable: Emulator terminated with exit code -1073741795
```

Comment: According to https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/external/qemu/+/1858426 it was removed because of performance problems and the arm64 translation system of newer Google images should be used instead.

Comment: do u know how to launch arm64 emulator successfully ? genshin impact doesn't work on arm64 translation system.

Comment: I don't think that an arm64 capable emulator will help you. usually the performance of an emulated arm64 system is so low that even regular apps are lagging. Playing a 3D game on such a system is out of scope, even if you would own a high-end PC system worth 10k USD.